# How can I make a command line command work for any user?

Tags: command-line, cmd

Is there any way that I can use CMD magic to where any one can type it in and it work for them? For example: This command works for me

RD /S "C:\Users\Kyle\FolderToDelete"

How can I make a command that will work for anyone? This is what I would like it to do.

```
RD /S "C:\Users\%UniversalUser%\FolderToDelete"
```

Before you think I am trying to do something malicious to someone's computer, I'm not. 
In a game I play, there was a recent messup with the game, and players need to delete a certain directory and redownload it in order for it to work.

Comment: With `%UniversalUser%` - do you mean the "all users profile"? Is %public% what you are searching for?

Comment: I mean, I would like it for that to work for any user. For example, if the user was John, or Jane, '%UniversalUser%', the command would work for anyone. I'm sure there's a name for it.... I just don't know it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `%user%` or `%userprofile%` The following two lines are equivalent:

```
RD /S "C:\Users\%User%\FolderToDelete"    
RD /S "%UserProfile%\FolderToDelete"
```

EDIT: As Sujay Sarma correctly stated: `%user` will not work if the user name is munged or the user has been migrated. For example if you upgraded or inplace reinstalled, your username may still be "kyle" but your folder will be "kyle_000" or something.

Comment: I don't think this is it. If I type 
`RD /S "C:\Users\Kyle\FolderToDelete"` everything works fine. If I type `RD /S "C:\Users\%User\FolderToDelete"` I get an error saying "The system cannot find the path specified." (yes, the folder IS there)

Comment: you simply forgot a `%`... (it's %user%`, not `%user`)

Comment: @Stephan: That will not work if the user name is munged or the user has been migrated. For example if you upgraded or inplace reinstalled, your username may still be "kyle" but your folder will be "kyle_000" or something.

Comment: @SujaySarma: Thats true for `%user%`, but `%userprofile%` should work.

Comment: @Stephan I apologize, that was a silly typo, however, I am still getting the problem. This is a screenshot that... is... baffling me as to why it would happen. [link]http://s5.postimg.org/6yafefc13/Capture.png EDIT: You've got to be kidding me. I made the typo AGAIN when I retried it.

Comment: @KyleMe : Your commands are not working for the following reasons: [1st one] -- you have the `%` symbol only at the beginning. It should be `%User%`. [2nd one] -- you need to run this command from the `C:\Users` folder. [3rd one] -- This obviously worked, there is no output.

Comment: @Stephan I noticed in your answer you put %UserDomain%, but in your comment you put %userprofile%.. I tried %userprofile% and that worked like a charm. I'm not sure if %UserDomain% is incorrect or not, so I will not edit your post. Thank you for the help. Sujay Sarma, thank you as well, I didn't even notice your answer somehow.

Comment: @KyleMe Sorry, the "domain" was an error due to lack of coffee. I corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

The root directory of the user's folder is stored in the Windows environment variable `%UserProfile%`. All you need is this one variable to trigger the delete.

```
RD /S "%UserProfile%\FolderToDelete"
```

(Eg: For a username of "Kyle", `%UserProfile%` will evaluate to "C:\Users\Kyle").

will do the trick.